# Load video with second audio stream in chromecast custom receiver

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

My asset has 2 audio streams: english and hungarian.
Sometimes hungarian is the second audio stream, not the first, therefore not the default.

I want to always start playback with hungarian audio.
I based my code from [Cast-Player-Sample](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample/blob/master/player.js).

**Attempt**:

After `this.onMetadataLoadedOrig_(info);` ([here](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample/blob/master/player.js#L687)) I did:

```
this.protocol.enableStream(2, true); //enables hungarian
this.protocol.enableStream(1, false);
this.player_.reload();
```

It doesn't work: player goes to IDLE state and nothing is played.
BTW, `protocol` comes from `this.protocol = protocolFunc(host)` ([here](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample/blob/master/player.js#L838))

**The only way** I could make it work was to start with the default language and change it only after player is in PLAYING state.

How can I start playback with audio other than default (first)?

Comment: I suggest you file a bug with a sample stream and logs: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to enable/disable protocol streams in the [onManifestReady](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.Host#onManifestReady) callback. This way you don't need to call `player.reload()`.

**onManifestReady**

> Notifies the host that a manifest or a master playlist has been loaded and processed by the protocol. This callback can be used to disable the streams enabled by default by the protocol and enable desired streams instead.